# Groovy - configuring logging properties depending on environment

Tags: logging, groovy, log4j

I am writing a simple Groovy application that needs to do some logging. The actual properties of how things are logged will depend on the particular environment. For instance, while developing I just want to log to the console, in test and production I may want to write to a file and in production I may want to send email for the most severe events.

Right now what I am doing looks like this:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator

class BaseClass {
    protected config

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BaseClient.class)

    def BaseClass(env) {
        def configFilePath = // whatever

        config = new JsonSlurper().parseText(configFile.text)[options.env]

        def logConfigFilePath = ['somelogdir', config.log_file].join(File.separator)
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(logConfigFilePath)
    }
}
```

and then all my classes that need to do logging inherit from `BaseClass`.

In this way, I can specify a different filename for each environment, and I get to read the logging configuratio from there. But it seems a lot of boilerplate, and forces me to use a hierarchy that may not be ideal.

On the other hand, [here](http://www.canoo.com/blog/2010/09/20/log-groovys-new-and-extensible-logging-conveniences/) I see that I can obtain a logger with a simple annotation.

> Is there a way to get different loggers depending on the environment - which may be set at runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on tim_yates's answer, use a groovy file to configure log4j.  For example:

```
// log4j.groovy
log4j {
    rootLogger="DEBUG, A1"
    appender.A1 = "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"
    appender.'A1.layout' = "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"

    if (System.properties['env'] == 'prod') {
        appender.'A1.layout.ConversionPattern'="prod %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n"
   } else {
        appender.'A1.layout.ConversionPattern'="dev %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n"
   }
}
```

Then make your script use it:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab(group='log4j', module='log4j', version='1.2.17')

import groovy.util.logging.Log4j
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator

@Log4j
class Test {
    def dosome() {
        log.info('Logging!')
    }

    static main( args ) {
        def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File('log4j.groovy').toURL())
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(config.toProperties())

        new Test().dosome()
    }
}
```

And finally, launch your program with the environment in a system property:

```
groovy -Denv=prod Test.groovy
```

Comment: Will the line `PropertyConfigurator.configure(config.toProperties())
` apply globally to all loggers? Because otherwise, this is what I am already doing in my question, and the problem at hand is exactly that I do not want to have these lines in all classes that need logging

Comment: Yes, calling `PropertyConfigurator.configure` will configure all the loggers.  There's no need to do it in every class.  Once at the start is enough.

Comment: Anyone know how to do the equivalent for log4j2? Googling hasn't pointed to an answer yet.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to simply put a `log4j.properties` file on your classpath.

Given this test script:

```
@groovy.util.logging.Log4j
class Test {
  def dosome() {
    log.info( 'Logging!' )
  }

  static main( args ) {
    new Test().dosome()
  }
}
```

If I run it from the command line:

```
groovy -cp log4j-1.2.17.jar Test.groovy
```

it doesn't print anything as it isn't set up to log INFO messages by default.

However, if I write a log4j.properties file ([taken from the docs for log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Configuration) and altered to log ):

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Print the date in ISO 8601 format
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Then run it again with this properties file in the classpath:

```
groovy -cp log4j.properties:log4j-1.2.17.jar Test.groovy
```

We get:

```
2012-07-16 16:08:47,524 [main] INFO  Test - Logging!
```

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is **not** getting a different file name depending on the environment. That one is the easy part, even without the slurper. What I am not able to do is feeding this configuration into Log4j. I am able to create and use loggers with a given configuration file, as I do in my example, but then I have to do this for each class that needs logging. Or I need to make all them inherit from a common class.

Comment: In other words, assume I am able, by any means, such as JSONSlurper or ConfigSlurper, to obtain a set of properties. How do I tell Log4j to use that configuration once and for all, even for logger instances that may be already created, say by an annotation?

Comment: @Andrea changed my answer...hope I'm closer this time (and hope it helps)

Comment: Closer, but not quite :-) If I rely on a file named log4j.properties on my classpath, then I cannot change the configuration based on the environment. So now it should be clear what is my issue: how can I read different properties files based on the env? One solution is what I post in my question. But it only allows me to configure loggers that I create manually. This clashes with the desire to inject loggers automatically. I would like to be able to apply this configuration for all loggers past, present and future

Comment: @Andrea You could have a log4j.properties for each environment?