# Grails: How do I get log.debug statements to display in the console

Tags: java, grails, logging, console, log4j

I'd like to use log.debug statements and have them logged to the console, but I don't want all  grails internal debug statements to be logged there too. How do I just configure all classes in my packages to log debug output to the console?

Comment: Have you read through the [logging](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#logging) section of the [Grails User Guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of log4j.properties file that achieve what you want:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, Console
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM HH:mm:ss} [%-5p] %c{2} - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.yourpackage=DEBUG, Console
```

Comment: Any chance you'd know how to write that in Groovy?

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504197/groovy-configuring-logging-properties-depending-on-environment