# logging in Groovy

Tags: logging, groovy

I am new to Groovy scripting. for troubleshooting/debug purpose i would like to write the informations in a logfile. i have to write my actual codes as per following skeleton.

```
import java.util.List;
import com.test.build.api.scripting.XXX;
**import import java.util.logging.Logger**

class MyTest 
{
  **static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger (MyClass.class.getName());**
 def init()
 {
    // HERE I WANT TO LOG THAT INIT WAS CALLED
   }

     def destroy()
      {
        }

            def process(List<XXX> xxxy)
                 {
                  // Reuse following skeleton for processing events
                        try
                           {
                             // Do Something
                  // HERE I WANT TO LOG THAT SOMETHING WAS DONE ABOVE
                             // Do Something
                  // HERE I WANT TO LOG THAT SOMETHING WAS DONE ABOVE
                             // Do Something
                  // HERE I WANT TO LOG THAT SOMETHING WAS DONE ABOVE
                             // Do Something
                             }
                 }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
       {
         return
          }
           }
             }
```

all this i want to log in a file i.e c:\temp\myscripting.log

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868180/groovy-script-and-log4j

Answer (score 1):

I personally recommend [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html).

As @tim_yates comented, log4j is great.
I've used log4j in my groovy projects. The [tutorial](http://www.laliluna.de/download/log4j-tutorial-en.pdf) is very self exploratory.